# Libreoffice Writer: change the toolbar button font color to automatic

Tags: libreoffice

It seems the default is to have a red button there, which is odd: clicking it makes selected font red, but wishing that is a rare possibility.

[image]

This seems to be normal behavior - as said under [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/writer-toolbar-font-color-icon-wont-change-default/31643).

But in most cases when I need that is in order to set selected text to my "default": pasting text sometimes it has different colors and I want to quickly set that to normal color, not red, and I would prefer not to have to click twice.

The default of that button can be changed but the change is not remembered.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking on the LibreOffice forums

Comment: "_pasting text sometimes it has different colors_" - you know that Ctrl/Shift/V (plain paste) removes all the formatting - including colours?

Comment: @roaima - I know about Ctrl-Shift-V, which displays the "paste special" list of options. I have a key to paste directly unformatted text (CTrl-Alt-Shift-V, don't remember if it's default or custom), and I know how to edit those, even how to create new ones with saved macros. A macro can be created for a button to set the automatic color and a toolbar button can be added for that. But what I ask is simpler. - As for asking on askLO, see the link in Q.

Comment: On my version of LO the Ctrl/Shift/V simply pastes unformatted. No options.